# How to set subplot title on the bottom in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, title

I know how to set a title with `ax.set_title('title')`, but i want to place the title on the bottom.

I found another post asking similar question and the answer suggests setting the xlabel as the title. However, I don't want any boarder so I used `ax.axis('off')` and that this method does not work.

Comment: you can set the `y` kwarg to control the vertical position of the title. e.g. `ax.set_title('title', y=0.1)`

Comment: @tmdavison doesn't really work in this case, because my plot and subplots are with different height ratios

Comment: That doesn't matter, just adjust the y value to whatever value you need it to be. Alternatively just use `fig.text` or `ax.text`and place it wherever you like. And if those still don't work, create a [MCVE] to explain why they don't